# How can I deploy with a comment?

Tags: octopress

When I do a:

```
rake deploy
```

How can I add a comment?  Right now the comments are auto generated with the date:

```
Site updated at 2014-03-30 23:21:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in the rake file.

```
multitask :push do
  puts "## Deploying branch to Github Pages "
  puts "## Pulling any updates from Github Pages "
  cd "#{deploy_dir}" do 
    system "git pull"
  end
  (Dir["#{deploy_dir}/*"]).each { |f| rm_rf(f) }
  Rake::Task[:copydot].invoke(public_dir, deploy_dir)
  puts "\n## Copying #{public_dir} to #{deploy_dir}"
  cp_r "#{public_dir}/.", deploy_dir
  cd "#{deploy_dir}" do
    system "git add -A"
    puts "\n## Committing: Site updated at #{Time.now.utc}"
    message = "Site updated at #{Time.now.utc}"
    system "git commit -m \"#{message}\""
    puts "\n## Pushing generated #{deploy_dir} website"
    system "git push origin #{deploy_branch}"
    puts "\n## Github Pages deploy complete"
  end
end
```